# error when the size of the json that is sent to ThingsBoard using http has more than 1000 variables

Tags: json, http, variables, size, thingsboard

Carrying out different tests on the sending of data and their respective times to the ThingsBoard platform, an important problem has arisen. When I send a single JSON file with 1001 variables using HTTP to a ThingsBoard platform device, no variables arrive on the platform. However, when the JSON file has 1,000 variables, the 1,000 variables are delivered to the platform. Does the platform have any limits so that the JSON files that are sent do not have more

Comment: If you're not using Thingsboard Cloud I'd recommend ssh'ing into your server and checking the logs. If ubuntu you can use `journalctl -u thingsboard.service -f` or something like that. Typing from memory so could be wrong. A hint for what to google I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any hard limit, which could be restricting the data transfer in that case. The performance depends on the setup of your ThingsBoard instance (including Database, Queue, etc.).

Please have a look at the logs of ThingsBoard or the use the API usage dashboard in the ThingsBoard Web UI.